# Strange issue with sequences

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I just had an issue with creating a new entry in a table which boiled down to a duplicate id being generated.

When looking at the sequences defined in the DB, I noticed, that ALL sequences I have were duplicated. Each sequence `table_column_id_seq`, which were the original ones, now has a twin `table_column_id_seq1`.

How could this happen? What must I have done wrong?

Comment: What tools do you use to administrate the database? Does your application use an ORM that does create the schema from the entity definition?

Comment: Did you look at the postgres logs?

Comment: I use Mojolicious and DbVisualizer and have not looked into logs as I have no direct access to the DB server :(